# Long Polling on HttpClient result and streaming into the CSV file

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient

**Question 1:**
How do I implement the same behavior? But instead of `Observable.interval`
it will be invoked by callbacks.

**For example:**
*I have `5000ms` interval but my server is extremely slow, and it doesn't get back the result after `5000ms`. But the next call is invoked after `5000ms`. I don't want it like that. I would like after the result is return from the server it will invoke the next call.*

**Question 2:**
*How do I stream the result immediately to csv file without creating multiple files one after another. For this current implementation I use `FileSaver` which works in `IE11`. I would like to continue using it.
Is there a way to stream data to file instead of collecting it into the array, cause I have large dataset's. Like 1m rows and so...* 
Example:

```
const progress = Observable.interval(1000)
  .switchMap(() => this.messageService.getResults(query))
  .map(messageResult => messageResult)
  .subscribe((data: MessagesResult) => {
    inProcess = true;
    if (!data.isMoreResults && data.auditMessageList.length === 0) {
      this.fileSaver.save(`result.csv`, csvData);
      inProcess = false;
      this.logger.info('Download file finished...');
      progress.unsubscribe();
    }
    const start = this.filterModel.offset * this.filterModel.limit;
    const rows = [...csvData];
    rows.splice(start, 0, ...data.auditMessageList);
    csvData = rows;
    if (inProcess) {
      this.logger.info('Exporting in progress...');
    }
    query.offset++;
  }, error => this.logger.error(error));
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have found out using `Observable.interval` won't 'wait' for the rest of the stream.

I generally use `repeatWhen` with `delay`

```
const progress = Observable.defer(() => this.messageService.getResults(query))
  .repeatWhen(notifications => notifications.delay(1000)) 
  ...
```

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/a0rz6nLv/19/

I don't understand the rest of you code very well.

Don't use `progress.unsubscribe();` in `subscribe` method. Instead consider using [takeWhile](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile) or [takeUntil](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeUntil) - both will complete the observable for you.

```
.takeWhile(data => data.isMoreResults  data.auditMessageList.length > 0)
```

Also buffering results can be done for example by using [reduce](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-reduce) or [toArray](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toArray)

```
.reduce((accumulator, data) => data.auditMessageList.concat(accumulator), [])
```

Side effects are best handled by [do](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) operator

```
.do({
  next: () => {
    inProgress = true;
    this.logger.info('Exporting in progress...');
  },
  complete: () => {
    inProgress = false;
    this.logger.info('Download file finished...');
  }
})
```

Regarding second question - I don't know - you should be able to stream csv from the server. If you cannot modify the server maybe someone else will know how to do it on client...

Comment: @m1ch4Is this dies after the 1st request. How to make it run up until it has reached the terminate status?

Comment: @IamStalker Honestly I don't understand your code - I've written some more suggestions that might help. Maybe try to remove everything that starts with `this.` from the question (to make it more self contained) or create jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

### Question 1

Here's an example implementing a function that calls itself when it gets a response.

**Backend:**

1. Simulate a slow backend that responds within 5s and 10s
2. At each response, the server gives the current `request_number` and a `state`
3. For the 3 first responses, the `state` is `active`, after that, the `state` is `closed`

code:

```
/* Mocked backend. I'm slow, like really slow */
class SlowBackend {
  MAX_ITERATIONS = 3; // suppose you're reading a table and you have pagination, with 3 pages
  currentIteration = 0;

  constructor() {}

  getStuff() {
    console.log(`**Request N. ${this.currentIteration}**\n[Back] : received a request from the front`);
    const responseDelay = Math.random() * 5000 + 5000; // response between 5s and 10s
    let state = "open";
    if(++this.currentIteration > this.MAX_ITERATIONS)
      state = "closed";

    return Observable
      .timer(responseDelay)
      .map( () => {
      console.log(`[Back] : Responding after ${responseDelay} ms`)
        return {
          request_number : this.currentIteration,
          state : state
        };

      })
  }
}
```

**Front:**

This is basically your component.

```
class Frontend {

  isPollingActivated = true;
  responses = [];


  constructor(private backendService) {
    this.backendService = new SlowBackend(); // connection to backend
    this.requestOnRegularBasis();
  }

  requestOnRegularBasis() {
    if (!this.isPollingActivated)
      return;

    this.backendService.getStuff()
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(`[Front] : received response from server. State : ${response.state}`);

        // Choose one of the following blocks, comment the other according to what you need

        // Block 1 : Sync processing example
        console.log(`[Front] : doing some sync processing`);
        this.doSomeSyncProcessing(response);
        this.requestOnRegularBasis();

        // Block 2 : Async processing example
        // console.log(`[Front] : doing some async processing`);
        // this.doSomeAsyncProcessing(response)
        //    .subscribe(this.requestOnRegularBasis);

      })
  }

  private doSomeSyncProcessing(response){
    if(response.state == 'closed'){
      this.isPollingActivated = false; // stop polling
      this.saveDataToCsv();
    }
    else
      this.responses.push(Object.values(response).join(';')) // csv line separated by ';'
  }

  private saveDataToCsv(){
    const headers = ['current_request;state']
    this.responses = headers.concat(this.responses)
    console.log('saving to csv : ', this.responses.join('\n'));

    // Uncomment this to use FileSaver API
    /*
    const blob = new Blob(headers.concat(this.responses), {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "my_responses.csv");*
    */
  }

  private doSomeAsyncProcessing(response){
    return Observable.timer(1000).map(() => this.doSomeSyncProcessing(response));
  }

}
```

**output:**

```
**Request N. 0**
[Back] : received a request from the front
[Back] : Responding after 5482 ms
[Front] : received response from server. State : open
[Front] : doing some sync processing
**Request N. 1**
[Back] : received a request from the front
[Back] : Responding after 7489 ms
[Front] : received response from server. State : open
[Front] : doing some sync processing
**Request N. 2**
[Back] : received a request from the front
[Back] : Responding after 9627 ms
[Front] : received response from server. State : open
[Front] : doing some sync processing
**Request N. 3**
[Back] : received a request from the front
[Back] : Responding after 5806 ms
[Front] : received response from server. State : closed
[Front] : doing some sync processing
saving to csv :
current_request;state
1;open
2;open
3;open
```

### Question 2

You can't.

At least not using `FileSaver`. Because it doesn't support writing chunk by chunk. When you instanciate your `Blob`, you have to
have all your data ready.
There are some libraries that support chunks but they are either meant for server side (node.js for example), or extremely browser specific.

Check this : [Save client generated data as file in JavaScript in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287586/save-client-generated-data-as-file-in-javascript-in-chunks)

*Note :*

if you are trying to store a 1M rows csv in client's machine using js, then maybe something is wrong with the architecture.
Because this is not a common usecase for browsers. Clients are supposed to have weak machines, an thus receive processed,
light, easy to parse information. For that matter, you can for example construct the csv in the server side which will
have all the rights to write stream files, and decent processing/memory capacity.

**Demo : Question 1**

http://jsbin.com/rojutudayu/2/edit?html,js,console

**Demo : How to download the blob ?**

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/e9d941381475b5df8b7d7691013401e171014e89/FileSaver.min.js"> </script>

<script> 
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
</script>
```

Comment: suppose I'm invoking API, I do not know max iteration and I don't have constant timeout. Suppose the server is extremely slow and it's returns responses after while each time different timeout.

Comment: In my example, there isn't a constant timeout. It varies between 5s and 10s, but if it varied from 1s to 1minute, it would be the same. If the server fails to respond after ~150 seconds, the connection will hangout, and you can't fix this if you use http requests. In this case you would have to open a websocket for example, or use firebase like technology. As for the maximum number of iterations, it isn't a problem, you can replace 3 with 5000 iterations. The problem is you will have to store the blob (or csv) once its size reaches something like 600Mb, and reset your array of responses.

Comment: hmm, interesting I've read in the post about the js chunks that you gave here, that It's can handle 1gb of data. That would be good to me. And how can I start download it as a chunk using the browsers download progress. Like you downloading simple big file?

Comment: According to , [FileSaver documentation](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#supported-browsers)  you can go up to 500Mb in Chrome, although other posts say you can go up to 2Gb. I guess you should test this in some browsers to get your answer. As for saving the files, I edited my example and included a demo. Basically, once you construct the blob, you can download it as if it was coming from a URL.

Comment: I edited my demo in jsfiddle too, you can go check it out. Now when the backend terminates, you download the csv automatically.

Comment: I would like to append the data on each request. Not after finish download

Comment: When you can create one csv at each server response. But you cannot append data to an already existing csv using FileServer, it doesn't handle this. The thing is browsers don't let you access to local storage easily, that would be a huge security problem. So you can't append to an existing file because that involves read+write. 
However, you can write multiple csv files, and at the end, merge them all into one single file. Does that seem like a reasonable solution to you ?

Comment: I knew it. Thank you. Just for a research purposes.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1:**

Use `forkJoin`. It will wait for all Observables completed.
When you combine with `delay(5000)`, the minimum time is 5s. If API response isn't returned before 5s, it still wait until the result returned ([demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyGZwj?editors=1112))

```js
const stream1$ = of(1).pipe(
  delay(5000)
);

const intervalTime = Math.random() * 5000 + 5000

// replace with your API stream
const stream2$ = of(intervalTime).pipe(
  delay(intervalTime)
);

forkJoin(stream1$, stream2$)
  .subscribe(([_, s2]) => {
    console.log(s2);
  })
```

**Question 2:**

If the file is large, you should let Web Browser handle it. It's better to save file in server, then return a link to download it. For small file, the performance is not the issue. You can store file data in RAM then save file once.

Edit: FileSaver Developers recommend using [StreamSaver](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js) if the file is large. You should take a look at it

> StreamSaver.js takes a different approach. Instead of saving data in client-side storage or in memory you could now actually create a writable stream directly to the file system (I'm not talking about chromes sandboxed file system)
>
> StreamSaver.js is the solution to saving streams on the client-side. It is perfect for webapps that need to save really large amounts of data created on the client-side, where the RAM is really limited, like on mobile devices.