Chunk downloading of the big files right to the hard drive
I have this method to download files. But I want to have a possibility to download files more than 1GB. Is it possible to do it and download it chunk by chunk, because as for me it is really bad to store so much data in the clients memory.
        const list = this.selectionService.getListValue();
        const areAllSelected = this.selectionService.getIsAllSelectedValue();

        const link = document.createElement('a');

        this.loadingText = 'Exporting images...';
        this.showLoading = true;
        this.absolutePosition = true;

        await this.projectImagesService
            .downloadFilteredZip(event.imageSetId, list, areAllSelected)
            .then(response => {
                const contentDisposition = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
                const filename = contentDisposition
                    ? contentDisposition.split('filename=')[1]
                    : `image_set_${event.imageSetId}_${Date.now()}.zip`;

                const href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.body);
                link.download = filename;
                link.href = href;
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
                this.showLoading = false;
                this.absolutePosition = false;
                this.loadingText = 'Uploading...';
            });
    }

And this is that is happening in the downloadFilteredZip
downloadFilteredZip(imageSetId: number, list: Array<string | number>, allSelected: boolean) {
        const offsetFilters = this.getOffsetFilters();
        const areAllSelected = list.includes('all');

        const url = `image-sets/${imageSetId}/archive?${this.serverApiService.rebuildObjectToQuery({
            ...this.filters,
            ...(!areAllSelected && offsetFilters),
            ...(!areAllSelected && !allSelected && { ids: list }),
        })}`;

        return this.serverApiService.get<Blob>(url, { responseType: 'blob' });
    }
}

I am using Angular, but I have some restriction from team, so I have to use thi serverApiService predefined methods

How I've done that in the past is have a call to the api to generate a one-time code using a random GUID and creating a hash and storing the criteria for the download with it.   It caches that information for a short time and has a separate url to download the file using that hash.   The client then creates a link directly to the api call to download providing that hash and the browser downloads directly from the api.

best to let the browser process and return File from backend.  Browsers/devices have limited storage.  Use:   if POSTing request.

Yes, but I am trying to emulate functionality when you trying to download a big chrome file and you have something like .crdownloading

Maybe check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287586/save-client-generated-data-as-file-in-javascript-in-chunks

I think anyway you go you'd need to use up memory = size of file.

So, the solution was to use this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API
Yes, it doesn't support all browsers,so in the case if the current client is not supporting it I show the alert, that it will be using RAM for this procedure and do it as I did before
